# LocationSource for Google Map android

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have  a Location Manager Class that im using for location updates.

I also have a small Map Fragment in my activity that i want to center on the location that my Manager is spitting out.

I have my map set to enable myLocation so that i can see the blue dot illustrating where i am.
GREAT..

now i am also updating the camera for the map on location updates to the lat and lon i am getting from my locationManager but the map is not centering on the blue dot.  which makes me think that the map and my location manager have a different idea of where i am.

I looked into mMap.setLocationSource inhopes that i could tell my map to use my location manager as the source but I am getting very little in the way of documentation as to what the class LocationSource even is.   can someone illustrate to me how i can make my map use my location manager as it's source?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocationSource` is not a class, but an interface with two functions.

You need to create a class, that implements it and:

In `activate` you are passed `LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener listener`, for  which you need to keep a reference.

In this function you would also normally start requesting locations from `LocationManager`. When you get a `Location` from `LocationManager` in your `LocationListener`, you need to forward this to `LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener listener`.

In `deactivate` you simply stop requesting locations.

For an example look into:

`ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\src\com\example\mapdemo\LocationSourceDemoActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

in your map fragment just implement `OnMyLocationChangeListener` then set `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this)` for the mapfragment then anytime `onMyLocationChange` gets called update the camera to the position given because when that gets called the blue dot moves.

your location manager and the maps location are 2 different things